How to specify the verticalAlignment of a container composable by a percentage?
Is it possible to specify the vertical aligment of a container by a percentage of the height of the container? for example, 20% of the height.
I only can find default ways like verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
For example:
LazyRow(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, <--- I need this to be 20% 
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp, Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
    ) {
        items(section.options) { menuOption ->
            HorizontalMenuOption(
                option = menuOption,
                buttonWidthPercentage = buttonWidthPercentageInFloat,
                onClickAction = onClickAction
            )
        }
    }


Yes, there is a BiasAlignment, in your case the Vertical variant. You specify bias as a float value where bias of -1 represents alignment to the top, a bias of 0 will represent centering, and a bias of 1 will represent bottom. So for 20%, you can do this:
LazyRow(
  verticalAlignment = BiasAlignment.Vertical(-0.6f),
)


hmm, there was missing "n" in the example, sorry

well, thank you, finally, to migrate values between 0 (top) to 1 (bottom) to that -1 to 1 system I did this: value*2-1
